# Expanding map fragment on push of a button

Tags: android, google-maps

I offer the possibility to enlarge the map fragment on the push of a button. In previous times I used this code

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

map.setLayoutParams(p);
```

While this worked fine with Google Maps v1, it doesnt compile anymore with V2.

What is the V2 way of achieving this?

```
XML with fragment:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainmtc" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/dontcare"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<fragment
   android:id="@+id/map"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/maindesc"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

Comment: No it doesnt, it says
The method setLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) is undefined for the type GoogleMap

Comment: are you getting error? If So post your stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the Following code.

```
<fragment
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_below="@id/maindesc"
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

This will help you  to get rid of your error.
Hope it heps.

Comment: won't work. Get a compile error SupportMapFragment cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: XML added to question